# How to enable/disable toolbar items?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, toolbar

How do you make a gtk.ToolButton disabled so that it is 'greyed out'? Like this:

[image]

How do you make it enabled again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `set_sensitive` method. If all you need is to disable/enable the button, you should call the method on the button; the argument should be `True` for enabling and `False` for disabling:

```
button.set_sensitive(True)    # enables the button
button.set_sensitive(False)   # disables the button
```

If you are dealing with actions, you may want to disable/enable the action associated to the button (this ensures that other widgets that may be related to the same actions, e.g. menu items, are enabled/disabled too), and call the `set_sensitive` method on the `gtk.Action` instead (although this is a different method from the `gtk.Widget` one, the usage is exactly the same; except that the button will not be enabled if the parent `gtk.ActionGroup` is disabled).